# Unable to create UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

For my current app I'm using `UIStoryboard` and graphically setting the initial View Controller,but when I again try to set `initialViewController` using `UINavaigationContoller` popup with the exception saying that

> `[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]:` attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]’

I figured out the exception which is in this line

```
 UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
```

But when I change the above line to

```
 UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
```

I won’t get any exception.

I'm writing code considering the `UIStoryboard`, but I guess that exception code is for `XIB`.

What is happening here?

Comment: Isn't the "detailViewController" nil? Sure looks like it.

Comment: have you check your detailViewController? I think it is only declared not initialised.

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure that you are created detailViewController before assign to NavControler.

```
   // You must:
  UIViewController *detailViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];


   UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
```

If you are using storyBoards, add as star viewController a UINavigationController and connect the root segue with your detailViewController. (Also you can make an outlet of your NavigationController in order to put some properties by code.)

Answer (score 0):

First import DetailViewController and the create object like below code

```
DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:detailVC];
```